dotnet htop and dotTrace
we updated some applications from dotnet 6 to 8, the performance increase was noticeable. However on one app htop reported the the CPU% went up, strange, so we ran dotTrace and it showed the same increase. However when we switched from Real time (CPU instruction) to Thread time measurement it showed that dotnet 8 consumed way less CPU time, and showed that a big chunk of time was spent waiting on a database read in sockets.
Is htop a useful tool when looking at performance?
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/profiler/Basics._Time_Measurement.html#real-time-performance-counter
